# JQuery load function adding string to url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a Javascript function that loads a php page with passed `GET` variables into a div on button press:

```
function loadMorePosts() {
var loadFeed = "php/feed.php?u=<?php echo $u; ?>";
$("#userPosts").load(loadFeed);
}
```

This is called through a simple `onClick` event on a button.

When I click the button I get a 505 error in the console and can see that it is adding a string to the end of the url. For example:

```
php/feed.php?u=Admin&_=1394533348555
```

The part after `php/feed.php?u=Admin` is not meant to be there.

The `loadFeed` variable is not used anywhere else in the entire site.

If I remove the `<?php echo $u; ?>` from the end of the URL, I can see (using `var_dump($_GET);` in my feed.php) that it is still sending the random string.

As it increases each time I press the button I think it may be a time string but not sure.

This is driving me crazy! Please help!

Comment: I am pretty sure that is a generated unique ID to avoid caching.

Comment: it's actually the current timestamp from client side

Comment: btw, that must not be the main cause of your 500 error, you should looking for another reason

Answer (score 0):

It's the JQuery **cache-buster** feature : https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-turn-off-cache-busting-in-getscript

Turn off it by setting the cache to true :

```
cache : true
```

If you use some JQuery plugins, this may be one of them which active it with :

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false})
```

Answer (score 0):

The string being added to the end of your URL appears to be something that is being used to prevent any caching issues, to me it sounds like it may be a Timestamp, since you said it increases?

A 505 error means the following:

> The server does not support the HTTP protocol version used in the
>   request.

Meaning that your web server doesn't like the request that you're making, it could be something as simple as needing to a protocol to your URL perhaps?

http://yourlocaldomain.com/php/feed.php?u=Admin

I suggest you check your server logs for further clues!